# about python datetime type

Tags: python, datetime, types

What's the equivalent type in types module for datetime? Example:

```
import datetime
import types
t=datetime.datetime.now()
if type(t)==types.xxxxxx:
    do sth
```

I didn't find the relevent type in types module for the datetime type; could any one help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> type(t)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> type(t) is datetime.datetime
True
```

Is that the information you're looking for? I don't think you'll be able to find the relevant type within the `types` module since `datetime.datetime` is not a builtin type.

Edit to add: Another note, since this is evidently what you were looking for (I wasn't entirely sure when I first answered) - type checking is generally not necessary in Python, and can be an indication of poor design. I'd recommend that you review your code and see if there's a way to do whatever it is you need to do without having to use type checking.

Also, the typical (<strike>canonical?</strike> *pythonic*) way to do this is with:

```
>>> isinstance(t, datetime.datetime)
True
```

See also: [Differences between isinstance() and type() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python), but the main reason is that `isinstance()` supports inheritance whereas `type()` requires that both objects be of the exact same type (i.e. a derived type will evaluate to `false` when compared to its base type using the latter).

Comment: In this case, it would be preferable to say `type(t) is datetime.datetime` vs. using `==`.

Comment: it would be preferably to use `isinstance`

Comment: agreed. `isinstance` is better than `is`